# PHP - if file_exists not working for image

Tags: php, file-exists

Right, as simple as this is supposed to be, I simply cannot get this code to work.
I am trying to check whether a users avatar image exists, and in case it does not, use the default one instead. Now, even though the image exists and filename, path, spelling, format, etc. are correct, `file_exists()` always returns `false` claiming that the file does not exist.

```
  <?php
    $avatar = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/ihg/dist/img/user'.$_SESSION['ID'].'-128x128.jpg';
    $default = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/ihg/dist/img/user_default.jpg";

    if (!file_exists($avatar)) {
        echo "<img src=\"$default\" class=\"user-image\" alt=\"User Image\">";
    } else {
        echo "<img src=\"$avatar\" class=\"user-image\" alt=\"User Image\">";
    }
  ?>
```

Is this a server side issue or is the code faulty?

EDIT:
I also tried using the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable and absolute paths, but no result.

Comment: Why does the default use double-quotes instead of singles after the server variable?  Anyway, could it be a folder permissions issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_exists()` accepts a file path rather than a URL.

To determine whether an image exists based on a URL you need to check the response type instead.

Since these are local resources you simply need to switch from using a URL to the full server file path. (`$avatar = '/path/to/root/...`)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: The problem with that solution is that the image is part of my navigation bar, which is present throught different locations on my server, hence need the dynamic `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` path to always address the same folder. Problem is, the document_root doesnt seem to work either...

Comment: Have you tried outputting `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and verifying you're getting the location you expect / calculating the path accordingly?

Comment: just did and found the problem :) I was missing a `/` after the `$_SERVER['DODUCMENT_ROOT']`, things are working fine now. THANKS!